# Can we use the existing customers for dynamic crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Currently, we cannot process about 500000 requests/year for about 8 million customers so we decide to re-design our CRM by using the Dynamic CRM.

The question is: How we can use existing customers on separate database with the Dynamic CRM database?

Any help is appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to do an import of your customer data from your legacy system into your CRM system.  There are basically three ways to do this:

1) User the built in CRM import wizard.  I don't recommend this for large volume or complicated data.

2) Use a tool that integrates with the CRM services to create CRM records.  I usually use SSIS packages with the CozyRoc adapter.  There are also a number of third party tools out there which I am not familiar with (Scribe seems to be the most talked about).  All of these methods have one thing in common in that creating records through the CRM services is slow.  With 8 million records it could take you days to import your data.

3) Insert your contacts directly into CRM using SQL.  This method is not supported and there are a number of potential pitfalls.  However this method is fast... inserting 8 million records might take you 10 or 20 minutes.  If you are interested in this approach I would be happy to give you more information.

Comment: Just to add to Zach's answer, I've used both scribe and SSIS for intigrations, and if you have the technical knowledge to use SSIS you should use it. Scribe has a number of pitfalls, including cost, performance and bug related issues. The "ease of use" is almost not worth it.

Comment: I agree with Arthur. We use SSIS and C# combination to integrate our records. This way you can compute and modify column values on the fly. We had nothing but bad experience with Scribe.